# How to get image from bytes array in php?

Tags: php, codeigniter

How to get image from bytes array in php ? i have string of byte array and i want to generate a image.

I have tries this code below.

```
$arrayData = array(
    'status' => 404,
    'message' => 'Not Found'
);

$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$obj = json_decode($json,true);


$img = isset($obj['image']) ? $obj['image'] : '';  


print_r($img); die;


$filename = $finalimage . '.' . 'jpg';

$filepath = base_url().'uploads/apifiles'.$filename;



file_put_contents($filepath, $finalimage);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this code below

```
$image_string = 'byte_strng';
$data = base64_decode($image_string);
$im = imagecreatefromstring($data);
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

Comment: That was quick. You answered within 40 seconds from the question was asked. Did you have the answer in your CTRL + V pretyped?

Comment: Hey vishal you are going good but you forgot '$' before 'byte_string' :)

Comment: No, Coolbuddy its string.